# How to make a Dialogflow fallback for specific intents

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to make a chatbot to allow users to book items.  I have 2 departments with items, so I have made 1 intent for each department.  Department A has boardgames, Department B has computer equipment.

I've set up my intents so a user can ask "I want to book Monopoly" or "I want to book a laptop" - those queries work.

Now, I want to be able to handle the user asking "I want to book a room".  That query won't match any of the training phrases for either of the departments, but I do want to give the user a context-specific answer of "We don't have that item available".

How to I configure an intent to match "I want to book [noun]", where [noun] is an unknown thing?

Comment: It isn't clear how you expect it to respond to "I want to book an elephant" in a "context sensitive" way. What kind of context do you expect it to be able to respond to in this case? Perhaps you can update your question to provide further examples of how you think it should behave or longer conversations that illustrate what you want.

Comment: @Prisoner.  That's part of the problem - there is no context.  If a user accesses the chatbot and the first thing they say is "I want to book a room" - then there is no context.  I believe we figured it out though, so I'll answer my own question.

Comment: I meant "context" in a non-technical way. You said "want to give the user a context-specific answer", and now I get what context you were talking about (the context of them asking to book something, not the context of a Department).

Answer (score 1):

We solved this by creating a Book "anything" intent.  It uses the built-in `@sys.any` parameter.  So we defined phrases like "I want to book @sys.any".  This intent seems to be matched only if the intents for department A and B do not match.  In this way, it is a fallback of sorts that matches for all booking questions for unknown "things"

Comment: In addition to this, to make sure, you can also lower the priority on this Intent.

Comment: @Prisoner Thanks for the priority tip - I didn't know about that.

Comment: Glad that it helps!